# Wifi Hotspot, adding VPN breaks DNS?

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, vpn, dns

With my rasp Pi, I made a Wifi AP (on wlan0) and I keep the raspberry connected to internet (eth0). The Rasp is not only used for surfing the public web, but also to get sensitive datas on one server.

So I tunnelled it like this :

**[users/clients] <==wifi/wlan==> [[Rasp]] <==VPN/eth==> [Server/Data] <====> WWW**

But when I run  `openvpn` & the config, I lose DNS:

- if openVPN is **off** : clients enter www.example.com and get it displayed
- if openVPN is **on** : clients enter www.example.com and after 10 seconds (timeout) they get "DNS_PROBE_ERR_NO_INTERNET" . If they enter IPs, they dont get this issue, it works as usual.

I used `isc-dhcp-server` (/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) to manage clients routing, dhcp and DNS (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4).

IP forwarding is 1.

To sum up, launching VPN breaks the DNS, actually breaks INTERNET FORWARDING - more generally -. I tried to use `bind9`, no success.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: After more investigations: It is not a matter of VPN. There is "NO INTERNET" for the Wifi AP clients . Since DNS are Google ones (online), obviously there is no more DN solving.

Comment: Does your comment mean you solved this? If yes, then please put this in an answer OR, if you think the question has no value, delete your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser - this is an OpenVPN question, not a Raspberry Pi one.

The short answer is probably that your routing with the VPN up has changed sufficiently that you can't reach the DNS server anymore.  You should look at your routing table before/after launching the VPN, and then modify the config as necessary to fix the issue.